# How to determine which property is the default property for databinding?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection, windows-forms-designer

Given a Class of X that has multiple properties that are bindable, how do I determine which one should be the default property to select via reflection?

In the Winforms designer you can select Databinding.  How does Visual Studio determine that "EditValue" should be the default property to bind to rather than say "Text"?

[image]

I already know how to get properties and attributes from the object, but I'm missing something that would tell me which one to use as default.

Comment: It uses [`DefaultBindingProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultbindingpropertyattribute?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) attribute of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rely on [`DefaultBindingProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultbindingpropertyattribute?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) attribute of the class.

For example a `DateTimePicker` is decorated with `[DefaultBindingProperty("Value")]` but a `ComboBox` is decorated with `[DefaultBindingProperty("Text")]`.

You can create a function like following, to get name of the default binding property of a control:

```
public string GetDefaultBindingPropertyValue(Control c)
{
    var att = c.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true)
        .OfType<DefaultBindingProperty>().FirstOrDefault();
    return att?.Name;
}
```

**Side Note**

You may be interested to these attributes as well for some complex scenarios:

- [`LookupBindingProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.lookupbindingpropertiesattribute?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8): Specifies the properties that support lookup-based binding. List controls like `ComboBox` and `ListBox` are decorated by this attribute, `[LookupBindingProperties("DataSource", "DisplayMember", "ValueMember", "SelectedValue")]`.
- [`ComplexBindingProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.complexbindingpropertiesattribute?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8): Specifies the data source and data member properties for a component that supports complex data binding. `DataGridView` has been decorated by this attribute, `[ComplexBindingProperties("DataSource", "DataMember")]`.